# NullPointerException during class testing

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, nullpointerexception

So I made a die class that is supposed to create die, and then allow me to roll them, pull their values and number of sides.  My problem now is that I cannot roll the die during testing as it throws a NullPointerException.

Here's the die class code:

```
package com.catalyse.die;

import java.util.Random;

public class Die
{
    // instance variables 
    private static int dieNum = 0;
    private int myDieValue;
    private int myDieSides;
    private Random rand;

    // Dice Class Constructors


    public Die()
    {
        dieNum++;
        this.myDieValue = 1;
        this.myDieSides = 4;
    }


    public Die(int numSides)
    {
        if ((numSides < 4) || (numSides > 100)) {
            System.out.println("Error! You cannot have more than 100 sides or less than four!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            myDieSides = numSides;
            myDieValue = 1;
        }
    }

    // getter methods


    public int getDieSides()
    {
        System.out.println(myDieSides);
        return 0;
    }


    public int getDieValue()
    {
        System.out.println(myDieValue);
        return 0;
    }

    // setter methods

    private void setDieSides(int newNumSides)
    {
        myDieSides = newNumSides;
    }

    public void rollDie()
    {
        myDieValue = (rand.nextInt(myDieSides) + 1);
    }

    // other methods

    public void printDie(int dieNum)
    {
        if (dieNum == 1) {
            System.out.println("Die Value: "+myDieValue);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Die "+dieNum+" Value: "+myDieValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the testing class.

```
package com.catalyse.die;

public class TestDieClass
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Die One = new Die();
        Die Two = new Die(50);
        Die Three = new Die(99);

        One.getDieSides();
        One.getDieValue();

        Two.getDieSides();
        Two.getDieValue();

        Three.getDieSides();
        Three.getDieValue();

        One.rollDie();
        Two.rollDie();
        Three.rollDie();

        One.getDieValue();
        Two.getDieValue();
        Three.getDieValue();
    }
}
```

Here is the error

```
4
1
50
1
99
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.catalyse.die.Die.rollDie(Die.java:83)
    at com.catalyse.die.TestDieClass.main(TestDieClass.java:27)
```

Comment: As I suggested, it deserved a new question. But then why did you change your code? Your previous code in the `rollDie()` was correct.`Random rand = new Random(); int i = (rand.nextInt(myDieSides) + 1);`. You changed it and thus the error.

Comment: Yeah I realized that there was a rand already declared at the top and it seemed redundant, I just forgot to initialize the one up top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 myDieValue = (rand.nextInt(myDieSides) + 1);
```

You haven't initialized `rand` so   rand  is `null`

So,

```
 private Random rand= new Random();
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed my issue, I hate when I miss the little things.